# app list is showing 401 Unauthorized

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to access my account. I attempted to sign in. It seems like I successfully signed in but the url indicates 'guest'

https://developer.here.com/web/guest/myapps

When I attempt to list my apps, it get

Unable to get apps because of org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized

Is there an email address or phone number where I can get assistance on this?

-Kelly

Answer (score 0):

The [FAQ](https://developer.here.com/faqs) is unclear about this, but since this is an infrastructure issue rather than a code problem, the best place to get a response on an issue like this would probably be the [Nokia Developer Forum](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/forumdisplay.php?280-Nokia-Location-APIs).

What **should** happen if you are not logged in is that the page says *"These pages require authentication"* and a password challenge box is displayed - Just a guess but maybe you are suppressing this with a pop-up blocker?? Eventually the forwarded url should be something like: `https://developer.here.com/myapps`